# Return value at the front of a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just saw some codes by others.

```
labels = ["{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
print(labels)
```

The output is

```
['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '90-99']
```

How to understand this? Are values returned at the front of the for loop?

Comment: Google `List comprehensions`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 3):

This line,

```
labels = ["{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
labels = []
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    labels.append("{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 9))
```

Let's test it out:

```
labels = ["{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]

another_list = []
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    another_list.append("{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 9))

print(labels == another_list)
# True
```

It's called [List Comprehension.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Also, you have `range(0, 100, 10)`: `range` is "[an immutable sequence of numbers.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)"

You can see the numbers like this:

```
In [1]: list(range(0, 100, 10))
Out[1]: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the for loop.

`for i in range(0, 100, 10)` starts with `i=0`, and goes to `i=100`, in intervals of 10. So, `i = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40 , 50, ..., 100]`.

And then the `.format(i, i+9)` is putting the value of `i`, and `i+9`, separeted by `-` in `labels`.